# Kotlin: How can I have a function accept a vararg along with a function that accepts the same number of elements used in the vararg?

Tags: kotlin, variadic-functions, static-analysis

Basically, as currently setup, we have code looking somewhat like this:

```
fun variableLength(str1: String, storedFunc: (String) -> String): String {
    //some manipulations
    return storedFunc(str1)
}

fun variableLength(str1: String, str2: String, storedFunc: (String, String) -> String): String {
    //some manipulations
    return storedFunc(str1, str2)
}
fun variableLength(str1: String, str2: String, str3: String, storedFunc: (String, String, String) -> String): String {
    //some manipulations
    return storedFunc(str1, str2, str3)
}
```

And so on. Obviously, this is ugly, non-DRY code that we'd like to fix up, but we want precompiler errors when we try to call the `variableLength` on a number of string inputs that don't match up with `storedFunc`'s number of inputs. Note that we are using IntelliJ Idea as an IDE, if that matters.

So is there a way to turn this into something similar to

```
fun variableLength(vararg strs: String, storedFunc: (vararg String) -> String): String
```

while keeping the precompiling errors? Note that there was a suggestion in the comments about using a custom linter, which would be accepted as well with a basic description of how to go about it. Note that we currently probably use the default lint for Gradle, whatever that is, but are probably fine switching to one in standard use for Kotlin.

Comment: It's not possible. And I'm almost certain I've seen repetitive code like this in the standard library. `varargs` must always be the final argument so the compiler can parse it, and there is no mechanism in the syntax for indicating how many elements are in the varargs.

Comment: In kotlin, varargs don't have to be the final argument, I know that much. You can access the others using a name call. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that feature because I never use it. Never mind. But I do know there is  no compiler constraint for number of varargs, and especially for matching number of varargs to another number of varargs in a functional type.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to dodge the second vararg (as I know the length I want for it: the same as the first vararg) and instead somehow have a manufactured explicit demand for a function of a certain length.

Comment: Maybe with some extremely sophisticated custom linter? There is no support in the language for anything like that.

Comment: Any idea how I'd approach that (no need for a full answer, just an outline)? I'd definitely accept that as an answer, though I've never done anything with lint before!

Comment: I've never done it either, sorry.

Comment: As a curiosity on this, is there different functionality between the 1 used string or the 3 used string? Is it the same functional approach, just providing a function signature to support this? If it is the same function I would have some potential solutions.

Comment: Can you add more info about the string manipulation? Is it the same for every arg? Can the manipulation be split, and performed separately from the function call? If the arguments were in a list, could they be combined using `fold()` or `reduce()`?

Comment: @BenjaminCharais There's no difference in functionality. The key thing is the calling of the function. In reality, it stores this in a class as a list and a function to be called later.

Comment: @aSemy It's the same regardless of args. Just a way to call the stuff would be fine. The issue with accepting as a list is two fold: first, checking the length of the list against the number of args in the func, but second and more important, is that we'd like to call the function without wrapping it in a list.